# Add subview on tableView cells causes a sad patchwork

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, subview

I want to give a chat aspect to a table view of messages in my iPhone app. 
In order to perform a quality render I add two subviews: the text and the "container" which is just a view with background color.

Even if it works the first time, when I scroll, it becomes really messy because it keeps adding lots of subviews.

- [Here you can see it when clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHgEi.png)
- [And then when it has become messy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1F9x.png)

Here is the function to handle the transform, it's called when scrolling.

```
func configChatCell(cell: UITableViewCell, text: String, color:UIColor)
{
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let fixedWidth = cell.bounds.width - 150
    let textView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: CGFloat.max))
    textView.text = text

    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: min(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    textView.sizeThatFits(newFrame.size)
    textView.frame = newFrame
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()


    self.rowHeight = textView.frame.height+20


    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = color
    print(textView.frame.height+10)
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: textView.frame.width+50, height: textView.frame.height+10)
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5


    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(textView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(view)
}
```

If I remove the subviews each time I scroll, nothing appears on screen.

Can somebody help me to find a solution? Or is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cells are re-used, so you are adding the additional views many times.  It is better if you create a custom UITableviewCell subclass and add the views either using a nib, storyboard or in code in the cell class

Comment: I don't think it necessary to add label and round corner view every time scrolled. maybe it works that config cell in table view source data's cellForRowAtIndexPath. I will create a project to test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly wrote up something for this.

It starts with the `ChatCell`

```
class ChatCell: UITableViewCell {

    var messageLabel: UILabel? {
        didSet {
            messageLabel?.text = message
        }
    }

    var message: String? {
        didSet {
            messageLabel?.text = message
        }
    }

    class func messageCell(withText text: String, leading: Bool = true) -> ChatCell {
        let cell = ChatCell()
        cell.message = text



        // Make the container
        let container = UIView()
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.contentView.addSubview(container)

        container.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8).active = true
        container.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).active = true

        if leading {
            container.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: leading ? 8 : 8*8).active = true
            container.trailingAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor(cell.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: leading ? -8*8 : -8).active = true
        } else {
            container.leadingAnchor.constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor(cell.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: leading ? 8 : 8*8).active = true
            container.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: leading ? -8*8 : -8).active = true
        }

        // Make the messageLabel.
        let messageLabel = UILabel()
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.addSubview(messageLabel)

        // Add constraints.
        messageLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(container.topAnchor, constant: 8).active = true
        messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(container.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).active = true
        messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(container.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).active = true
        messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(container.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).active = true

        cell.messageLabel = messageLabel

        container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.19, green:0.70, blue:1.00, alpha:1.00)
        container.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0

        return cell
    }

}
```

The cell also includes support for leading and trailing messages, for back and forth conversation. Perhaps make an array of tuples like this:

```
let messages: [(message: String, leading: Bool)] = [("Hello", true), ("My name is John Doe and this works quite well", false), ("I would agree", true)]
```

Then in your `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` you could do this:

```
let cell = ChatCell.messageCell(withText: messages[indexPath.row].message, leading: messages[indexPath.row].leading)
return cell
```

Let me know if this works for you. I tested it in a Playground and it works as expected[image: The result of using ChatCell and leading/trailing]

Comment: Thank you ! Useful and I think it's a good way to solve the problem.. however, I've still an issue after copying your code : there is a white layer above all of the cell and to see the message you have to click on it (white layer remains but behind the message). Moreover, container fit to the text only if I add container subview before return cell. Can you help me a little bit more ?

Comment: Ok I solved the white layer, it was a conflict before a previous declared cell. However problem about textfit still remains but I'll try to solve it. Really I thank you !

Comment: Glad to hear it mostly worked, so what's exactly happening with the text fit?

Comment: I can't add any screen in a comment.. I'm new on Stack. The text fit has a problem because there is no line break, each message goes out the subview and take just 1 row height. In your screen second message has a line break so I don't understand why it doesn't work on my project.

Comment: Oh okay, this is an easy fix. Just do this `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80` and this `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. This way the table view cells will automatically resize according to auto layout.

Comment: An easy fix as you say ! You're a king of god for me. Thanks

Comment: Just one more question (I forgot to precise). Is it possible to set width of the view in order to fit to the text too ?

Comment: Yes, and it's really easy too. The last line of the constraints for the containerView just replace it with this `container.trailingAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor(cell.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: leading ? -8*8 : -8).active = true` and it should do what you want.

Comment: It does the trick. Finally, can we align message on the right ? Because now it starts on 8*8, has a variable width so is not necesserily align on the right tableview side.

Comment: Okay, I am just seeing the issue now. I will fix it.

Comment: I just updated the post to include changes that enables the views to snap to the leading/trailing sides.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `configureChatCell` is called from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, then @Paulw11 is right; cells are reused, so you should only make changes *that are unique to that row in the table*. In your example, the *only* calls that you should be making in your method are `textView.text = text` and the ones to resize the `textView` to fit. Everything else should go in a dynamic cell prototype in the storyboard or, if you want to do everything in code (which I have a bad feeling you do), then put the rest of the configuration in a `UITableViewCell` subclass, then register that subclass with your table view.

Answer (score 0):

I write something like this. It's simple but can elucidate solution

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseid", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    let contentView = cell.contentView
    let subviews = contentView.subviews
    for view in subviews {
        if 100 == view.tag {
            let label = view as! UILabel
            label.text = self.datas[indexPath.row]
        } else if 200 == view.tag {
            view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

the key point is config every thing in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`
the view in code with tag 200 is a background view has same frame with label, I use layout constraint in storyboard to make sure its size and position.

[image: storyboard]

[image]